# Clickhouse lags at each query

Tags: clickhouse

Well, I have 2 servers located in the same place with about 1-2ms ping between each other: A and B. Clickhouse server with basic configuration is located on the A serever. 

I do 2 same queries: "SHOW databases". 

1. clickhouse-cli @ A server to localhost

2. clickhouse-cli @ B server to A server:9000

Server A: 0.002 sec.

Server B: 0.19 sec.

Next "SELECT * FROM table":

 1. clickouse-cli @ A server to localhost - 8 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.003 sec.

 2. clickouse-cli @ B server to A server:9000 - 8 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.15 sec.

And so on.. The same result I have while try to execute query at A server from my PC (about 0.19 sec). So each query executed from remote source has at least 0.1 sec.

It looks like latency but too much.. anyway I suppose that the latency shoud not affect the executuion time. So the question is: what do I do wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like a DNS latency. Have you tried plain IP address from B to A?

Comment: Hope it will solve after hardware replace.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, that doesn't sound like ClickHouse related problem, since localhost requests are ok. ClickHouse doesn't process localhost requests in some special way, so the problem is probably somewhere in your OS / network settings / hardware.